# UITableview, SDWebImage, cell reuse and UIImage problems

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

See video example here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A93hm.jpg

Have a tableview with images im downloading asynchronously from the internet. Im able to get them to populate correctly and without issue with either my own code or SDWebImage. My problem begins when I paginate more data to the end of the tableview. Pagination does work. As does all the text data, it all works and remains correctly throughout the tableview. The problem im having is with my ImageView. As you can see in the video, after pagination, the `UIImageViews` image changes all the cells from the previous call to what appears to be the image of whats in the most recent cell at the end of the tableview. What is driving this behavior and why is it only happening to my imageviews and what can I do to fix it?

ive tried setting the imageview image nil in `prepareForReuse` (against Apples recommendations) and it produces the same result.

Relevant code

API Call

```
 func downloadGamesByPlatformIDJSON(platformID: Int?, fields: String?, include: String?, pageURL: String?, completed: @escaping () -> () ) {
        var urlString : String?
        
        if pageURL == nil {
            urlString = "https://api.thegamesdb.net/v1/Games/ByPlatformID?apikey=\(apiKey)&id=\(platformID!)"
            
            if fields != nil {
                urlString = urlString! + "&fields=" + fields!
            }
            if include != nil {
                
                urlString = urlString! + "&include=" + include!
            }
            
        } else {
            urlString = pageURL!
        }
        let url = URL(string: "\(urlString!)")!
        var requestHeader = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        requestHeader.httpMethod = "GET"
        requestHeader.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestHeader) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("error = \(error)")
                completed()
            }
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    print("error = nil")
                    let json = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                    
                    print(json)
                    
                    if let jsonDecodedPlatforms = try JSONDecoder().decode(ByPlatformIDData?.self, from: data!) {
                        let decodedJSON = jsonDecodedPlatforms.data?.games
                        self.boxart = jsonDecodedPlatforms.include.boxart
                        self.baseURL = jsonDecodedPlatforms.include.boxart.baseURL
                        self.page = jsonDecodedPlatforms.pages
                        
     
                        self.games.append(contentsOf: decodedJSON!                
                            }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
```

Pagination

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
        
        if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {
            
            if !fetchingMore {
                beginBatchFetch() 
            }
        }
    }
    func beginBatchFetch() {
        fetchingMore = true
        print("fetching data")
        network.downloadGamesByPlatformIDJSON(platformID: nil, fields: nil, include: nil, pageURL: network.page?.next) {
            print("pagination successful")
            self.fetchingMore = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
                      
                  }
        
    }
```

cellForRowAt

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        
        cell.configureCells()

        //creating game object
        let game1 : GDBGamesPlatform?
        game1 = network.games[indexPath.row]

 //retrieving the filename information based on the game id
        
        if network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[0].side == .front {
            print(network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[0].filename)
            frontImageName = network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[0].filename as! String
            
        } else if network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[0].side == .back {
            backImageName = network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[0].filename as! String
            
        }
        
        if network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?.count == 2 {
        if network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[1].side == .front {
            frontImageName = network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[1].filename as! String
                       
        } else if network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[1].side == .back {
            backImageName = network.boxart?.data["\(game1!.id!)"]?[1].filename as! String
                       
        }
        }
   
        
        
        //creating image url string
        var imageUrlString = network.baseURL!.small + frontImageName
        print(imageUrlString)
        let imageURL = URL(string: imageUrlString)
        
        
        
        
        //if data exists for the front cover image download it, otherwise show default image
        if frontImageName != nil {
            
            cell.loadCoverImageWith(urlString: imageUrlString)
            
        } else {
            cell.tableViewCoverImage.image = UIImage(named: "noArtNES")

        }
        
        return cell
        
    }
```

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCoverImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewGameName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewGenreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewAgeRatingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCompanyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewReleaseDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundCell: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewCoverRearImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var gameCartImage: UIImageView!
    
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
           super.prepareForReuse()
        
        tableViewCoverImage.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
        tableViewCoverImage.image = nil
             }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
                                                  
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func loadCoverImageWith(urlString: String) {
        let imageURL = URL(string: urlString)
       
            
            self.tableViewCoverImage.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "noArtNES"), options: SDWebImageOptions.highPriority) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error downloading the image.  Error Description: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    let edgeColor = self.tableViewCoverImage.image?.edgeColor()
                    self.tableViewCoverImage.layer.shadowColor = edgeColor!.cgColor
                }
            }

        
        
        
    }
    

    func configureCells() {
        tableViewCoverImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5, height: 8)
        tableViewCoverImage.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        tableViewCoverImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        tableViewCoverImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        tableViewCoverImage.clipsToBounds = false
        tableViewCoverImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        backgroundCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        backgroundCell.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        backgroundCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        backgroundCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            backgroundCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            backgroundCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        } else {
            backgroundCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            backgroundCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    }
    
   

}
}
```

Comment: The url for subsequent pages is not setting include parameter. Looks like this is causing box art to be overwritten by empty content. Also check the scope for frontImageName and backImageName. They should be local to tableView(:cellForRowAt:)

Comment: @Dale

the URL for subsequent pages is returned in the JSON response and includes all the parameters from the original call.
url from JSON looks like:
'https ://api.thegamesdb.net/v1/Games/ByPlatformID?apikey=MYAPIKEY&id=7&fields=players%2Cpublishers%2Cgenres%2Coverview%2Clast_updated%2Crating%2Cplatform%2Ccoop%2Cyoutube%2Cos%2Cprocessor%2Cram%2Chdd%2Cvideo%2Csound%2Calternates&include=boxart%2Cplatform&page=2 '

Comment: @Dale interesting, changing the scope of front and back ImageName to local makes the previous images now default to the placeholder image after pagination.

Comment: Does the returned boxart on the subsequent page return box art from the previous pages? Probably not. You are appending the results for the games but setting the results for boxart.

Comment: @Dale I think you are onto something here, and its been something eating away at the back of my mind for a while now.  My problem is, in the JSON response boxarts come back as dictionaries and not as an array like the game data.  How can i take the returned box art data and append it if its not an array thats returned?   Here is an example of the returned JSON: https://pastebin.com/5bV6UTcx

Comment: Dictionary.merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:). See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127171-merge

Comment: @Dale That fixed the problem! It made total sense once you explained it.  If you can add it as an answer i can mark your answer as the correct one.  I dont believe i can do that from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and later calls to the API are appending the results for games to the array but overwriting the results for boxart. The results for the later pages will not include the boxart from earlier pages.

So, your boxart data no longer includes the art for earlier pages. The reason you are getting the image from the last item, is that the variables frontImageName and backImageName have the wrong scope, they should be local to tableView(:cellForRowAt:)

You need to **merge** the results of the API call with existing boxart dictionary by calling Dictionary.merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:). See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127171-merge for details

Answer (score -3):

It's a reusability issue. Try changing this line in cellForRowAtIndex.

```
tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell\(indexPath.row)")
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell\(indexPath.row)", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
```

Comment: That causes a crash as there is no cell named cell0, cell1, cell2, etc.  The cell identifier is cell.  How can I make the identifier change per cell, and if im changing the identifier each time doesnt that defeat the purpose of the cell being reusable?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I assumed that you knew cell must be registered with same ID we dequeue.

Comment: Thank you.  I currently have my reuse identifier set to "cell" in IB.  Should that be changed?  The only way i could get this running was to set the reuse identifier in code to "cell".  How will indexPath.row be fed into it if its expecting "cell"?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If you have a lot of data, this will cause memory issues since you are no longer reusing any cells. You are initializing a new cell for each row.

Comment: it is totally incorrect. You make `dequeueReusableCell` totally useless because all cells became unique